# SSIS project not working when reading from Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssis

I've been trying to create an SSIS project to read from an Oracle 11.x database to an SQL Server database.
When I set this up in Visual Studio 10 Shell, I do not receive any logs . It gives me a successful message but nothing happens.

I tried to connect to an Oracle 12c database and the same happened.

I tried to get data from an Oracle 11.x project and dump it into an excel file. I also tried to get data from an Oracle 11.x table and dump it into a new Oracle 11.x table (in the same database) and in both cases I got the following error:

> ### > TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Failed to start project
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Exception deserializing the package "The package failed to load due to
>   error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error
>   information can be specified for this problem because no Events object
>   was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This
>   occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails. ".
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>
> ---
>
> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from
>   XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this
>   problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error
>   information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML
>   fails.  (Package)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: we use SSIS to extract from our oracle db and load into sql server, it works, but we use 2008 R2 and we use the Oracle OLE driver, if that helps

Comment: Thank you Peter. We use sql server 2012 and we use Microsoft Connector v2.0 from Attunity

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted how you are trying to get data from oracle exactly so can say much about the error. I can only give my solution in 2008 r2:

create an oracle linked server in your sql server and then use an open query in the SSIS package to pull anything you need

Comment: Hi, I used the Source Assistant and the Destination assistant in SSIS